# Jada Samadhi , Jeeva samadhi and Siddha vithai does this lead to jnana and moksha?

Tags: moksha, samadhi, jnana

Swami Sivananda Saraswati - Says in hatha yoga when one collects all of his prana using either lambika yoga/khechari mudra and focuses it in his eyebrow center he goes into jada samadhi. This is more of an acrobatic feat of being buried under ground as breathless state is achieved and being in a hibernation or jada(inert) state where no knowledge of the supreme or transformation of the mind occurs.

There is this art of yoga called siddha vithai in south India where people practice Vaasi yoga and go into jeeva samadhi as it is being called. A state where complete breathlessness is achieved and the individual is called a Gnani and a jeevan mukta and is buried underground and considered immortal.

The definition of the two seem very similar. Jada state should be avoided but how do you know what vaasi or lambika actually leads to?

Comment: Siddha Vithai will definitely lead to Moksha.... Vaasi Yoga is art of absorbing directly Cosmic Prana into our body. There's a secret passage to crown of head in our body and Vaasi directly deals with that passage to attain Samadhi!

Comment: Jada -samadhi is an alternative name of Asamprjnata-samadhi so far as I know. This is one highest state of Samadhi. Making the body still by khechari mudra is not samadhi I think.It can be a mechanical process.Samadhi must bring the knowledge of the Supreme Self!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers gentlemen. There were two conflicting perspectives coming from very highly accomplished yogis of our age. **Swami Sivananda Saraswati** says the following about Khechari mudra and collecting all the prana from the body and focusing it inside the head when all breath ceases and comes to a stop which is the very definition of Vaasi by Agastya muni and Kagabujandar - [http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1228]. Here swami Sivananda saraswati discourages this as you would have read.

Comment: A conflicting approach is given by **Swami Rajrshi Muni** in the following [https://lifemissionusa.org/blog/maha-yoga-swami-rajarshi-muni]. He talks of a mahayoga mode of 4 stages **Mantra yoga** - Aaa uuu MMM implicit with raising and lowering vaasi. Then **hatha yoga** with 4 parts with asana (chandra naadi seat), pranayama (specific breath in Vaasi), mudras (hand and tongue for vaasi) shatkarmas ( purification avashtha from such practices). Then **Laya yoga** the layam stage of mind and desire completely sublimating and finally **Raja yoga** samadhi state culminating in siddha light deha

Comment: He has given stages in progression but Agastya and Kagabujandar have given direct method to Vasi. PURIFY the mind and enter Nishta. VASI will rise to head! Remember Agastya Siddhas Vasi yoga is different from Siddha Vithai Vasi taught by Sivananda Paramahamsa!

Comment: Agreed however is there anyone who can really teach agasthya muni's vaasi yoga?

Comment: Please use @username to notify me. Otherwise I wont get notified And second Agastya Muni's Yoga is secret and not known to outside world. Only if you meditate on Agastya he will come and give Diksha!